# How can I insert label in a scrollable canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

The scroll don't work at all. What's wrong in the code?
I'm using Python 2.7.16
I read that listbox and text widgets are used only for text. As I want to use labels, I'm trying to insert the labels in a frame, but as a Frame didn't scroll I decided to use a canvas. But I couldn't get it to work.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=200)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

canvas=Canvas(frame, bg='#FFFFFF', width=300, height=200, scrollregion=(0,0,500,500))

vbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL)
vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

canvas.config(width=300, height=250)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)

mylist = Frame(canvas, width=100)

for x in range(10):
    texto = Label(mylist, text='CODE', bd=2, width=7, relief=RIDGE)
    texto.grid(row=x, column=0)
    texto1 = Label(mylist, text='EQUIPAMENT', bd=2, width=20, relief=RIDGE)
    texto1.grid(row=x, column=1)

mylist.place(x=0, y=0)
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)

mainloop()
```

Comment: A Canvas only scrolls the drawing objects added to it via the various `.create_XXXX()` methods, not child widgets added by the normal geometry management methods such as `.place()`.  You need to use `.create_window()` instead.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper. I've modified the code but the scroll still don't work. "canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=mylist, anchor='nw')
in the loop - Label(mylist, text='CODE',  bd=2, width=7, relief=RIDGE).pack()"

Comment: When I use create_rectangle ou create_line directly in the canvas the scroll works.

Comment: I'm replacing the label by a create_text directly in the canvas and the scroll is working. That's the way. Thank you.

Comment: I'm using this: canvas.create_text((10, 50), text='CODE', width=7, anchor=NW, justify=LEFT) and the text is being written in a vertical direction rather than horizontal. Is there an option to make it horizontal?. Using Python 2.7.16 in windows 10.

Comment: Update: just increasing the width option it's written in horizontal position. I increased from 7 to 40. Someone said that create_text cannot write in vertical, but it's enough to set a low width.